# RecyclerView scrolls to top after adding items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that I use to display items in an activity. When I scroll to the bottom, I make another API call to fetch an additional set of data. When the items load, my RecyclerView scrolls to the top. I have tried the other solutions listed without success. I have attempted many if not all of the suggestions mentioned in similar threads. None of them worked for me.

**activity_see_more.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/see_more_frameLayout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the **SeeMoreActivity.java** I override the following method from the MvpView

```
@Override
public void loadPropertiesForCategory(List<Property> propertyList) {
    Preferences sharedPref = new Preferences(this);
    if (!properties.containsAll(propertyList)) {
        properties.addAll(propertyList);
    }
    sharedPref.setFilterList(properties);
    ResultListFragment fragment = ResultListFragment.setTag("see_more_filter");
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.see_more_frameLayout, fragment, "search").commit();
}
```

**ResultListFragment.java**

```
private void setListOfCategoryProperties() {
    page = 2;
    mSearchList = mPreferences.getFilterList();
    setListAdapter(false, false, View.VISIBLE, View.GONE, false);
    mResultRecycleView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            if (linearLayoutManager != null && linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == mSearchList.size() - 1) {
                ((SeeMoreActivity) getActivity()).setLoadPropertiesParamsAndCallApi(page);
                if (mSearchList.size() != mPreferences.getFilterList().size()) {
                    page++;
                    mSearchList = mPreferences.getFilterList();
                    //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mSearchList.size() - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public void listAdapter() {
    mResultRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    mResultRecycleView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mResultRecycleView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    mResultRecycleView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private void setListAdapter(boolean showDeleteButton, boolean changeVisibility, int showNoResult, int showNoSavedSearch, boolean reverseFavorite) {
        if (mSearchList != null && mSearchList.size() != 0) {
            if (changeVisibility) {
                setVisibility(View.VISIBLE, View.GONE, View.GONE);
            }
            mAdapter = new SearchListAdapter(R.layout.item_single_element, mSearchList, showDeleteButton, this, reverseFavorite);
            listAdapter();
        } else {
            setVisibility(View.GONE, showNoSavedSearch, showNoResult);
        }
    }

public void handleTags() {
        switch (mTag) {
            case "result_search":
                setListAdapterForHomeSearch();
                break;
            case "see_more_filter":
                setListOfCategoryProperties();
                break;
            case Constants.USER_FAVORITES_KEY:
                setListOfUserFavoriteProperties();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: May I ask when do you call the method setListOfCategoryProperties() ?

Comment: @ditocesartista Updated my post. It is called when the ResultListFragment is instantiated, a value is passed as the tag parameter which then triggers the appropriate action in the switch block.

Comment: And what does setLoadPropertiesParamsAndCallApi do? calling the API and updating mSearchList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell, but it looks like you're re-setting the adapter to a new adapter every time you receive more data.  That resets a bunch of internal state in RecyclerView, so that's probably what's causing this.

To solve it, you should leave the existing adapter in place and instead call one of the `Adapter.notify...` methods (probably `notifyItemRangeInserted`) to inform the adapter that more data has been added.  You could also use [`ListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter) and its `submitList` method to automatically handle it for you.

Comment: It was indeed that I was actually reinstantiating my fragment every time I made an API call. I fixed it by just instantiating it once, and then actually only adding new properties to the mSearchList.

Comment: Glad it's working!  If this answer was helpful, please feel free to upvote and/or accept it :-)

Comment: Tried upvoting, but seems like my accounts upvotes mean nothing on stackoverflow, atleast for now :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was  that I was creating a new instance of my fragment every time I made an API call. Now that I create only one instance and update the list by just adding new elements to it, everything works correctly.